# Explicit finite difference method for transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

So, here is an equation

$\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+a \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f(x, t), \quad a>0 \\
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1, \quad 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \\
u(x, 0)=\varphi(x), \quad x \in[0,1] \\
u(0, t)=g_{1}(t), \quad t \in[0,1]
\end{array}$

A scheme for it:

$\begin{array}{c}
\frac{U_{j}^{n+1}-U_{j}^{n}}{\tau}+a \frac{U_{j}^{n}-U_{j-1}^{n}}{h}=f_{j}^{n} \\
j=\overline{1, M} ; \quad U_{0}^{n+1}=g_{1}^{n+1}
\end{array}$

and there is an analytic solution:

$\begin{aligned}
a &=0.23 \\
u(x, t) &=x^{3}-\sin (2 \pi t x) / 2+2.5 t x
\end{aligned}$

It is easy to express $U_{j}^{n+1}$:

$U_{j}^{n+1} = U_{j}^{n} - \frac{a\tau}{h}(U_{j}^{n} - U_{j-1}^{n}) + f\tau $

It seems to be very easy to program this stuff, but I am struggling with it.. I just can't understand what is wrong! Solution just weird.. not even close to truth.

Please, check my code and tell me what is wrong

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# wave speed
a = 0.23

# spatial domain
xmin = 0
xmax = 1

n = 10 # num of grid points

# x grid of n points
X, dx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,n,retstep=True)
T, dt = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,n,retstep=True)

# initial conditions
def initial_u(x):
    return x**3

def analytic_u(x,t):
    return x**3 - np.sin(2*np.pi*t*x)/2 + 2.5*t*x

def f(x,t):
  return 2.5*x - np.pi*x*np.cos(2*np.pi*t*x) - a*(np.pi*t*np.cos(2*np.pi*t*x) + 2.5*t + 3*x**2)

# each value of the U array contains the solution for all x values at each timestep
U = []

# explicit solution
def u(X,t):
    if t == 0: # initial condition
        return initial_u(X)
    uvals = [] # u values for this time step
    for j in range(len(X)):
        if j == 0: # left boundary
            uvals.append(analytic_u(0,T[t-1]))
        elif j == n-1: # right boundary
            uvals.append(analytic_u(1,T[t-1]))
        else:
            uvals.append( U[t-1][j] - (a*dt/dx)*(U[t-1][j]-U[t-1][j-1]) + f(X[j],T[t-1])*dt )
    return uvals

for t in range(10):
    U.append(u(X,t))
    plt.plot(X,U[-1])
```

Comment: If its a coding bug, try simpler sub-cases, e.g. $f\equiv 0$, $g_1 \equiv 0$, $\varphi(x) = \Bbb{I}_{[0.4,0.6]}(x)$ which should give you $\varphi(x-at)$. How are the initial and boundary conditions defined?